# what's the optimal partition setup for a linux db server?

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration, installation, centos

My host wants to know how I want to partition my server before installing CentOS. I need to be able to do use xtrabackup to create quick backups from 20-50GB databases. I know I need to use a LVM, but I'm not sure how I would forward that to my host?

I currently have 1TB of usable space in RAID-10, how should I partition the array? this is only going to be a db server, only mysql and OS will be on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the partitioning of data in SQL Server is done for performance, recover-ability (separating log/data files to different physical disk arrays), and then management of data.  For example, if you have different logical drive letter names, you could look at the IO metrics for them separately through your monitoring solution.

It looks like you only have 1 large RAID 10 with 1TB of total usable storage.  Correct?  If so, at the end of the day, it's not going to matter too much from an architecture point of view since your hands are tied to having everything on the same spindle.

Now as to how to setup the drives on the LinuxOS, it depends on the scope and scale of the servers lifetime.  I'll let your guys decide on that how that should look outside of the vanilla:

- 1- swap (RAM X2 or whatever you guys decide)
- 2- /boot (Usually small primary partition - ext3)
- 3- / (big data drive)
- 4- / (log drive)
- 5- / (Backup Drive)

I would advise on separating the data and log drives for more granular performance metric collection, and separating the backup drive so they don't balloon up to a point where your data files have no room to grow.  Make sure to pre-grow your files when installing.

Again this is highly subjective and many opinions might differ.  Implement what makes most sense to you.

Comment: I understand different people might have different and better approaches, but please do post a reason for downvoting an answer so everyone can learn from your thoughts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only dealing with a single logical volume and have no control over physical placement of data or logs, there will be no performance advantage from any particular placement scheme. In addition to the standard Linux boot and swap partitions, you may want to place root (`/`), `/tmp`, and the MySQL data and log mount points onto separate partitions to isolate them from runaway space utilization -- this way a temporary file from a rogue process won't eat away your database disk space, and the database growing out of control won't bring the operating system down.